# Infinite loop dijkstra algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, search, nodes, dijkstra

I'm currently trying to learn the dijkstras algorithm. I think I've gotten the idea of it, it's just I have an infinite loop running when I trace back from the destination node to the start node.

```
public Node[] dijkstrasSearch(Node start, Node target) {
        //ASSUMPTION: Graph is not disconnected and does not require
        //the unvisited nodes to be visited after the algorithm stops
        
        ArrayList<Node> visited = new ArrayList<Node>();
        ArrayList<Node> unvisited = new ArrayList<Node>();
        
        HashMap<Node, Node> nodePD = new HashMap();
        HashMap<Node, Double> nodeValue = new HashMap();
        
        final int GRAPH_SIZE = 100;
        GraphLoader gl = new GraphLoader();
        Node[] nodes = gl.getNodes();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < GRAPH_SIZE; i++) {
            nodePD.put(nodes[i], null);
            nodeValue.put(nodes[i], Double.MAX_VALUE);
            unvisited.add(nodes[i]);
        }
        
        Node currentNode = start;
        
        nodePD.put(currentNode, null);
        nodeValue.put(currentNode, (double) 0);
        
        //Start Loop here
        while (unvisited.size() > 0) {
            visited.add(currentNode);
            unvisited.remove(currentNode);

            if (currentNode == null || currentNode.equals(target)) {
                break;
            }
            ArrayList<Edge> nextNodes = currentNode.getEdges();
            ArrayList<Edge> unvisitedEdges = new ArrayList();

            for (int i = 0; i < nextNodes.size(); i++) {
                Node getNode = nextNodes.get(i).getToNode();
                if (!(visited.contains(getNode))){
                    Double getNodeValue  = nodeValue.get(getNode);
                    if (getNodeValue == null || (nodeValue.get(currentNode) + nextNodes.get(i).getWeight() < nodeValue.get(getNode))){
                        nodeValue.put(getNode, (nodeValue.get(currentNode) + nextNodes.get(i).getWeight()));
                        nodePD.put(getNode, currentNode);           
                    }
                    unvisitedEdges.add(nextNodes.get(i));
                }
                if (nodePD.get(getNode) == null) {
                    nodePD.put(getNode, currentNode);
                }
            }
            
            double minEdgeValue = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            Edge nextNode = null;

            for (Edge unvisitedNode : unvisitedEdges) {
                if (nodeValue.get(unvisitedNode.getToNode()) < minEdgeValue) {
                    minEdgeValue = nodeValue.get(unvisitedNode.getToNode());
                    nextNode = unvisitedNode;
                }
            }
            
            currentNode = nextNode.getToNode();
        }
        
        ArrayList<Node> shortestPath = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Node tempNode = target;

        //Infinite loop? Is it my nodeHead hash that is wrong?
        while (tempNode != null) {
            shortestPath.add(tempNode);
            tempNode = nodePD.get(tempNode);
        }

        Collections.reverse(shortestPath);
        return shortestPath.toArray(new Node[0]);
    }
```

The output should be a node array representing the shortest path from the start node to the end node. The graph is 10x10. My code probably isn't as efficient as it could be but I'll worry about it later, just wondering why I get an infinite loop.

Comment: Please provide the code that initialises the input and calls this function.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it would be great if you created a Java fiddle with a sample input that reproduces this problem so we could debug it.

Comment: *"The graph is 10x10"*: have you tried anything with smaller graphs first, step by step increasing until you get the problem, and then using a debugger to step through the code to see at which place variables don't get the value you expect?